# Unexpected JDWP Error 21

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, midlet

HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(strDefURL + strBloggersURL);

I have this line throwing "InternalException: Unexpected JDWP Error: 21", I am using it to get some XML back from a servlet I have created. The odd thing is that the string later gets filled with the XML from the servlet. I am not able to parse this though and obviously need to debug from the top down, this being the first error in my code.

Unable to find a resolved ticket to date, I have added one myself: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=224188

Comment: did you mange to find the solution, i am also getting this error

Comment: @chetan To be honest it's so long ago (from my university days) that I haven't the faintest idea. I imagine that I was doing something stupid, else I would have probably added an answer to the question if I found a legitimate fix.