# J2ME XML Parsing

Tags: java-me, xml-parsing, midlet, jsr172, jdwp

I have another question about a "JDWP Error: 21" logged: [Unexpected JDWP Error 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016343/unexpected-jdwp-error-21)

I am trying to parse some XML I gather from a servlet into a J2ME MIDlet with the code below.  So far unsuccessfully, I think due to the JDWP error on my HttpConnection how ever the InputStream is filled with XML and once parsed everything inside the Document is null.

Has anyone got and ideas about the JDWP error, and also does that code look like it should work?

In MIDlet I am using JSR-172 API `javax.xml.parsers.*`.

```
if(d==form1 && c==okCommand)
    {
        // Display Webpage
         webPage = new TextBox(txtField.getString(),
                "",
                100000,
                TextField.ANY
                );
        Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(webPage);

        try 
        {
            HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://localhost:8080/Blogging_Home/Interface?Page=Bloggers&Action=VIEW&Type=XML");
            conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            int rc = conn.getResponseCode();
            getConnectionInformation(conn, webPage);
            webPage.setString(webPage.getString() + "Starting....");
            String methodString = getStringFromURL("");
            if (rc == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) 
            {
                    InputStream is = null;
                    is = createInputStream(methodString);            
                    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
                    DocumentBuilder builder;  
                    Document document;
                    try  
                    {  
                        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
                        document = builder.parse(is);  
                    } catch (Exception e) {  
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    }
            }
            else 
            {
                    webPage.setString(webPage.getString() + "ERROR:" + rc);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle here
            webPage.setString("Error" + ex.toString());
        }
```

Comment: are you using [tag:jsr172]? are `Document, DocumentBuilder, DocumentBuilderFactory` classes from some library?

Comment: JSR172 - javax.xml.parsers.*